# How to add multiple values returned by a function directly

Tags: function, go

I have the following code.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := 0
    b := 0
    a, b += getValues()
    fmt.Println(a, b)
}

func getValues() (a int, b int) {
    a = 0
    b = 5
    return
}
```

I want to directly add the multiple values returned by a function. I just want to if there is a provision like this in Go.

When I run the above code, I get the following error.

```
syntax error: unexpected +=, expecting := or = or comma
```

Comment: no, you can't do this in go

Answer (score -1):

You can use a helper method which takes a variadic number of parameters and just returns the slice created from the params

```
func aggregator(res ...interface{}) []interface{}{
    return res
}
```

If you want to escape the extra type assertion you can set the type you want to work with, in your case `int`, for the input and output parameters of the helper function. But here is an example using `interface{}`:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%d, %d", aggregator(f())[0].(int), aggregator(f())[1].(int))
}

func aggregator(res ...interface{}) []interface{}{
    return res
}

func f () (int, int) {
    return 1,2 
}
```

[Go Playground.](https://play.golang.org/p/elLyBIyEdv4)

Comment: Please don't do that. It's _far_ less readable than the natural alternative.